# SQL get top 10 and the rest in two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have question to a SQL query where I cant manage to come forward. I want to take the `SUM` of the top 10 values of a table as one column and the `SUM` of the rest as another to make a PIE graph which shows how many percentage the top10 takes in the whole:

I can for now get the rest or the top10 but not booth in one row:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(counted) as Rest
FROM 
    Northeast 
WHERE 
    counted < (SELECT counted 
               FROM Northeast 
               ORDER BY counted DESC
               LIMIT 10)
```

Any solution?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases support `row_number()`, so you can do:

```
select sum(case when seqnum <= 10 then counted end) as top10_counted,
       sum(case when seqnum > 10 then counted else 0 end) as rest
from (select ne.*,
             row_number() over (order by counted) as seqnum
      from northeast ne
     ) ne;
```

EDIT:

In SQLite, you can do:

```
select (select sum(counted) 
        from (select ne.* from northeast ne order by counted desc limit 10)
       ) as top10,
       (select sum(counted)
        from northeast
        where counted not in (select counted from northeast order by counted desc limit 10)
       ) as rest;
```

This works, assuming you have no ties in the data.

One ) was missing I addet it, the code above does the Job :)

Comment: Dont works, it gives my an error by the (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error [SQL: 'select sum(case when ... It can be that Pandasql from Python maybe dont support it